# Transforming nested network callbacks to RxJava2

Tags: java, rx-java2

I currently have to following implemented in an ugly nested callback model, I'm new to RxJava and I would like to use RxJava to remedy the issue.

Remote Data Source:

```
1st <> if the client is connected to remote db
    // yes, continue to check sign in
    // no, error, no connection
2nd <> if the user is signed in (user)
    // yes, continue to get user uid from (user)
    // no, error, user not signed in
3rd [] get uid from user
4th [] query user's items with uid
5th <> if query contain items (items)
    // yes, return a Flowable<list<item>>
    // no, return an empty list
```

Each step is meant to run in a sequential order. I think functionally the 1st step should be a Completable, 2nd step should be a Single returns an User object, but my requirement is for the 5th step to have a Flowable list of items as the last observable for downstream subscribers.

It is feasible to do given the design above? What operators or transformation should I use changing from Completable, to then chain another operation that is a Single, and then ultimately a Flowable?

Comment: as it is written, it's not clear what it is that you're exactly asking for. a dump of code?

Comment: thx for your response, I've clarify what I'm asking for in the question. Pseudo code with some hint would be great.